# Android Studio: SQLite database doesn't create

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am currently building a password manager app for myself. I plan to save the passwords in a SQLite database. For that I use this code:

```
package com.example.passwordmanager;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String COLUMN_PASSWORD = "password";
    public static final String PASSWORDS_TABLE = COLUMN_PASSWORD + "s_table";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
    public static final String COLUMN_SERVICE = "service";
    public static final String COLUMN_CREATION_DATE = "creation_date";
    public static final String COLUMN_USED_NAME = "used_name";
    public static final String COLUMN_USED_EMAIL = "used_email";


    public DatabaseHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context,  "passwordManager.db", null,1);
        Log.d("DatabaseHelper","Constructor reached");

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String createTableStatement = "CREATE TABLE "+ PASSWORDS_TABLE + " ( " + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COLUMN_SERVICE + " VARCHAR(40), " + COLUMN_PASSWORD + " VARCHAR(40), " + COLUMN_CREATION_DATE + " VARCHAR(11), " + COLUMN_USED_NAME + " VARCHAR(40), " + COLUMN_USED_EMAIL + " VARCHAR(40), master VARCHAR(20), firstTime BOOLEAN)";
        Log.d("DatabaseHelper","OnCreate1 reached");
        db.execSQL(createTableStatement);
        Log.d("DatabaseHelper","OnCreate2 reached");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+PASSWORDS_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);

    }


    public boolean addToTable(Registration profile){

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put(COLUMN_PASSWORD,profile.hashedPassword);
        cv.put(COLUMN_SERVICE,profile.service);
        cv.put(COLUMN_CREATION_DATE,profile.creation_date);
        cv.put(COLUMN_USED_NAME,profile.used_name);
        cv.put(COLUMN_USED_EMAIL,profile.used_email);

        long insert = db.insert(PASSWORDS_TABLE, null, cv);

        if(insert==-1){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }


    }
}
```

The problem with this code is, it just doesn't create the database or the folder of the database in data\data\com.example.passwordmanager. I tried outputting which methods it will reached when the constructor is called and I realized that it never reaches the onCreate method.

The DatabaseHelper class is only called once so for:

```
package com.example.passwordmanager;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.input.InputManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CreatingNewEntryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_creating_new_entry);


        DatabaseHelper dh = new DatabaseHelper(CreatingNewEntryActivity.this);
}
```

Is this a problem with the code? Do I have to give permissions in the manifest.xml? Did I mess something up with the emulator? The App starts fine, it just doesn't create the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `getWritableDatabase()` or `getReadableDatabase()` on your database helper to make the framework create the database file and trigger `onCreate()`. Just calling the constructor is not enough.

See also: [When is SQLiteOpenHelper onCreate() / onUpgrade() run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881992/when-is-sqliteopenhelper-oncreate-onupgrade-run)

Comment: But that doesn't explain why the database.db file and the folder for it are not created. The super in the constructor should create the database file (?) , but it doesn't

Comment: "The super in the constructor should create the database file" what makes you think that?

Comment: Oh you were right @laalto, I just tested it again and now its working. I thought the super creates the database because I read in the documentation that the constructor of SQLiteOpenHelper would create it, but I misread it.

Comment: Yeah. The constructor docs also say "The database is not actually created or opened until one of getWritableDatabase() or getReadableDatabase() is called." https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper#SQLiteOpenHelper(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory,%20int)